# Can run a asyncronoustask with the GPU?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gpu

I can run a asyncronoustask under GPU Thread??

I like run one process that it is very very heavy. I was intent with normal asyncronoustask but not is viable because it a lot of time to response.

Thanks!!

Comment: **Can Android renderscript run on GPU?**


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970165/can-android-renderscript-run-on-gpu?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can run a asyncronoustask under GPU Thread?

No. At most, via Renderscript Compute, you have a *chance* of processing being done on the GPU, but that is up to the device, not you. The GPU is only good for certain sorts of work, which is why you cannot use it via normal programming mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any alternative?? Thanks